# Find if an array is a combination without repetition

Tags: arrays, ruby, set, combinatorics

I have an array of five elements:

```
source = [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]
```

I can get the combinations of one element, two elements, up to those with five elements.

```
source.combination(1)
#=> #<Enumerator: ...>
source.combination(1).to_a
#=> [[:a], [:b], [:c], [:d], [:e]]
source.combination(2).to_a
#=> [[:a, :b],
# [:a, :c],
# [:a, :d],
# [:a, :e],
# [:b, :c],
# [:b, :d],
# [:b, :e],
# [:c, :d],
# [:c, :e],
# [:d, :e]]
source.combination(5).to_a
#=> [[:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]]
```

I have these arrays:

```
a1 = [:e, :c, :b]
a2 = [:e, :c, :e]
a3 = [:e, :b, :k]
```

The first is a combination of three elements, the second one is not valid since it has repeated elements, and the third one has one element that is not valid. For getting them, I can do something like this:

```
source.combination(a1.length).to_a.any? {|c| (c - a1).empty?}
#=> true
source.combination(a1.length).to_a.any? {|c| (c - a2).empty?}
#=> false
source.combination(a2.length).to_a.any? {|c| (c - a3).empty?}
#=> false
```

But I want to know if it is possible to calculate this without calculating all the combinations with the `to_a` method applied to the enumerator.

Comment: Can the array contain duplicate elements?

Comment: Should `[:e, :c, :b]` match even though it is out of order, i.e. not a combination?

Comment: Well it is the same set, not the same list, maybe it is not well explained

Comment: So you want to check if it is a `permutation`, not `combination`?

Comment: In my case, the order is not important, the only things is that the elements are the same, so is a combination of elements the result is a set so two sets with the same elements are the same combination. I'm working with sets

Comment: _"I'm working with sets"_ – but your example contains `[:e, :c, :e]`, i.e. an array with duplicate elements.

Comment: Yes, so it is not valid, and then it returns false, because is a combination using repited elements

Comment: Side note (since the answer is the best solution) the `to_a` is not necessary in any event since `any?` is an `Enumerable` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this method basically checks both source and sub array have common elements and those size of common elements should be equal to the sub array. You can do the check with array intersection.

```
source = [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]
a1 = [:e, :c, :b]
a2 = [:e, :c, :e]
a3 = [:e, :b, :k]

(source & a1).size == a1.size
 => true 
 (source & a2).size == a2.size
 => false 
 (source & a3).size == a3.size
 => false
```